# How to open a new popup and change it to new tab

Tags: javascript, popup, new-window

I want to open a new window but instead of having that window as like like it does, i want it to make it as a tabbed view.

I have tried the following:

```
var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
var URL = "https://www.website.com/cws/share?mini=true&amp;url=" + location.href;
var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);
```

The above opens as a new window i.e popup. And i tried the below for new pop

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
```

But i tried combining the above to procedures but with no luck. could someone tell me if its possible at all and or how to go about it. Thanks!

EDIT:

Actually i went through all the answers before asking, and this will explain how my question is different.

A pop up looks like this (and i know how to open it):
 [image: pop up image]

And a new tab looks like this: 
[image: new tab image]

Simply put, i want to convert the popup in image 1 to the new tab structure in image 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: You can't control how a new window is opened, it is a user preference in the browser settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: You cannot convert an already-opened window.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/9069367).

```
  function openInNewTab(url) {
      var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
      win.focus();
    }

openInNewTab('http://www.google.com');
```

I've tried this code sample my self, in my browser's console and it worked fine.

Like the person who answered in the link above said, try calling **openInNewTab()** in `onclick` event of your `DOM` to prevent pop-up blockers.

You can try copy pasting the following line in your browser's console (tested on Firefox and Chrome).

It should open google in a new tab:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank').focus();
```